# Returning distance in miles or kilometers from manhattan distance formula output

Tags: math, gis, haversine

I am running a taxicab distance function on a list of coordinates and I would like to convert the outcome integer to a mile or km quantity.  For example:

0.0117420 = |40.721319 - 40.712278| + |-73.844311 - -73.841610|

Where 0.0117420 is the output I would like to convert to mi/km.  How could I go about this?

Comment: Answered here... (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53873/calculate-the-distance-between-two-digital-lat-long-points)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a situation where you are trying to navigate from `(40.721319, -73.844311)` to `(40.712278, -73.841610)` where these are lat / lon pairs, and you want to navigate using a "Manhattan" routing rather than a direct great circle route.

It looks like you are considering these points as opposite corners of a "rectangle" where travel is only allowed along north, south, east and west headings to move from one point to another and where travel along the path always brings the traveler closer to the destination point.

An approximation of this is to find one of the corners of the bounding rectangle for all such paths.  There are two of them, one at `(40.721319, -73.841610)` and the other at `(40.712278, -73.844311)`.  So, you can pick one of these and chose that as a waypoint for approximating the length each possible "Manhattan routes" between the two points.  If we chose the first, you will need to calculate the distance from the starting point to the waypoint then to the destination point.  Such as:

```
l(0) = (40.721319, -73.844311)
l(1) = (40.721319, -73.841610)
l(2) = (40.712278, -73.841610)
```

Using the [Haversine equations](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) we see the distance from `l(0)` to `l(1)` is approximately 0.2276km and the distance from `l(1)` to `l(2)` is approximately 1.005km making the entire route about 1.2326km.

This is approximately the length of any "Manhattan route" you pick where the distance is strictly decreasing along the path taken between the two points.  There are also some errors due to the curvature of the Earth, but for points this close to each other and so distant from either of the poles, this should be good enough for most applications.